# How to Decrypt hashpasswords in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, encryption, pentaho

We have created few reports in Pentaho with PostgreSQL as data source. We have implemented the authentication of pentaho to take from PostgreSQL database users and roles tables but in the db Passwords are stored as hash passwords. So when we try to login to Pentaho with the username and actual passwords, login is not working as we passed the hash passwords to the pentaho server while configuring the security.

So can someone let me know how to decrypt the hashed passwords while retrieving them from the DB with the below statement so that we can pass actual passwords to the Pentaho server while configuring authentication.

SELECT username, password, enabled FROM USERS ORDER BY username(In this statement password should be the decrypted passwords but in the db hash passwords are stored)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/

Answer (score 1):

If the passwords are hashed, then there is no way to "unhash" them.  Hashing is a one-way process.  If they were encrypted with a key, certificate, passphrase etc, it would be possible, but hashing is designed to be one-way.  The only way to be certain of the passwords is to reset them to something else.